# Using Boost with IAR's C++ compiler

Tags: c++, boost, embedded, c++03, iar

I'm giving Boost a test drive for the first time for an embedded project.  I am using IAR 7.60.2 set to C++, Standard, With Exceptions, With RTTI and Destroy Static Objects.

I've copied-and-pasted build this [Boost Getting Started Example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#build-a-simple-program-using-boost) using Boost 1.62.0.

As you might have guessed by the existence of this question, it fails to build (first error is `Error[Pe439]: expected a ">" ...\boost_1_62_0\boost\type_traits\remove_reference.hpp 30`).

That line happens to include an rvalue reference, which is not supported in C++03.  There are hundreds of errors resulting from Boost's use of Modern C++ constructs like `T&&` and `constexpr`.

Unsurprisingly, IAR's is not one of the compilers that Boost claims it is tested against, but the fact that Boost can work with pre-C++11 compilers coupled with the existence of an IAR-specific header in boost/predef leads me to believe there may be a way to get it to build.

I've searched SO, the interwebs and some of Boost's source, but I cannot find any relevant information on how to use Boost with IAR, so I came to ask:

**1. Is there anything I should be doing to help Boost to recognize the
    IAR compiler I am using and its limitations?**

**2. Is there a mechanism to
    force Boost to build for a C++03 compiler?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Boost is a collection of libraries. Not all libraries support the same compilers. That said, there's common infrastructure including compiler detection. That's why I'm sure there's no `#define` for C++03.

Comment: Ok, then is there a way to get the common infrastructure to recognize my compiler (including the fact that it is limited to C++03)?

Comment: Well, you already discovered `boost/predef`. It looks like your compiler is recognized as such. But let me give you a more helpful suggestion: Boost 1.62 was released 2 years after C++14, while you're still struggling with a pre-C++11 compiler. You might be better off with an older Boost version.

Comment: I discovered it, true, but I guess I don't know how to use it, since even Boost's Getting Started example won't build--I'm trying to discover if I'm doing something wrong.  Or are you saying that 1.62.0 won't build under C++03?  That would be useful information, because then I know Boost won't work for me.  (I intend to use features introduced in Boost 1.61.0).

Comment: The "collection of libraries" means that some libraries will build, others won't. It's virtually all volunteer work, and supporting nice platforms will be hit and miss. On the other side, compiler companies like Microsoft make it a priority to keep Boost working. As in, they look at Boost to see which parts of C++17 to implement first.

Comment: Oh, I see--thank you for the clarification.  If I understand you correctly, there are common infrastructure settings.  If the setting I need isn't available in the common infrastructure settings (and "build as C++03" isn't available) then whether a feature works or not will be hit or miss.

I think I get it now--thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A summary of @MSalter's comments, above:

Boost is a collection of libraries of different ages built and maintained by different people, primarily as volunteers.  Some libraries are built to work with older versions of C++ and some require newer versions.

Boost has some common infrastructure to control certain settings.  If the setting someone is looking for isn't supported by the Boost common infrastructure (and "compile for C++03" is not), then whether a given library supports compilation under C++03 will depend on when it was made and/or whether or not it was specifically designed to do so.  There is no global language standard setting for Boost.

The solution is simply to try the features in question to see if they work in the environment being used.

Thanks to @MSalter for the clarification.